# How to use Jupyter notebook on TAILS OS

Tags: jupyter, tor

How can I use Jupyter notebook on Tails OS?

If I use the *unsafe browser* for web scraping or web publishing is there a risk of IP leakage?

Comment: Jupyter notebooks don't do web scraping or publishing, so your question doesn't really make sense.

Comment: All Jupyter notebook assets, as far as I can tell, are loaded locally, on localhost. Thus, there is no external connection, and you can run notebooks when offline. That is, I'm assuming you start the notebook from your machine, and are not using a publicly hosted notebook hub.

Comment: You can open a Jupyter notebook in a "safe" browser, if you're paranoid: just give it the same URL as that it uses in an "unsafe" browser.

Comment: you can run *any* Python code on Jupyter, including web scraping or publishing. Tor, the *safe* browser in Tails OS, cannot access localhost afaik.

Comment: Youc an run any Python from a command line as well; a Jupyter notebook has little to do with that. So then your question would be if connecting to the outside world, in whatever way/through whatever port, is "safe" (for some definition of safe; here, probably private/route masked).

Comment: If Wikipedia is to be believed, yes, it is safe, because "All its incoming and outgoing connections are forced to go through Tor" (first paragraph in Wikipedia).

Comment: That is true as long as you do not use the *unsafe browser*. That is why I am asking the question.

Comment: It says *all* incoming and outgoing connections. I presume that is on OS level. The browser is irrelevant in that case. (I better point to the [Tails front page](https://tails.boum.org/), which states that "all connections to the Internet are forced to go through the Tor network". Which I read that any connection made in whatever fashion: the (any) browser (or any other tool, such as ssh, ftp, ping, traceroute) all go through Tor.)

Comment: *All* connections except the *unsafe browser*:
https://tails.boum.org/contribute/design/Unsafe_Browser/

Comment: I guess you answered your own question: it the Unsafe Browser (what a name...) bypasses the Tor network, then anything executed from/through that browser, is not private.

Comment: Just run any Python code directly from the command line instead; then you don't need a browser that can access localhost.

Comment: I suspect that the notebook server has different permisions than the *unsafe browser* and therefore it won't leak, but would like to know if that is the case.